# Storing game data in TurnBasedMatch bytearray

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-play-services

Is there a preffered way of storing game data in the match data bytearray you can use in a turn based match?

For example:
We are making a board game with 16 game tiles. Each of the tiles has to have a certain value associated with it. Our idea is to simply use 16 fields in the byte array to represent each of these tiles.

Another example:
We also need to store information on up to four players. We will store positional data, movement points and some other stuff. Lets look at the positional data:
Each player will have an x and y coordinate. Since we will have up to four players, we are thinking of setting aside 8 fields in the byte array for this positional data.

Both of these examples will work, but is there a "good practice" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a chess application using the turn-based multiplayer api. I just had a byte array of size 64 in which I stored details about what piece is there: ie "white knight" etc etc and it works perfectly fine.

As far as "storing" game data using byte arrays: byte arrays are used to pass match data when you finish your turn. For example in chess, you would need to put where you moved to in the byte array so the opponent can receive that data and make your move on their screen.

If you add more detail to your question with context from your code I can help you more.